# Can the Kubernetes master be geographically seperate from the nodes?

Tags: networking, kubernetes, redundancy

If I were to setup a kubernetes cluster, would it be possible and viable to have the kubernetes master in datacenter A, while having the nodes in datacenter B? I know there can be issues with having nodes distributed over several datacenters due to the high latency between pods, but I am not able to find any documentation for seperating the master and nodes.

Am I correct in the understanding that if the master fails temporarily (e.g. due to a power issue in datacenter A), then the nodes will continue to function but without monitoring, health checks and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use cloud, then definitely not. If you use on-prem kubernetes then definitely yes. The only disadvantage of this set up will be setting up proper node labels to devide them by datacentre and pod affinity to schedule pods properly to a target datacentre.
More complicated set up will be sharing pods between datacentres. In this case you will need a "global" VPN so they can reach each other and their load balancers

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly the short answer is no, it is not possible to use nodes from different regions in single cluster.

However you can run clusters in [multiple zones](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/best-practices/multiple-zones/#walkthrough).

> Kubernetes 1.2 adds support for running a single cluster in multiple
>   failure zones (GCE calls them simply “zones”, AWS calls them
>   “availability zones”, here we’ll refer to them as “zones”).
>
> Multizone support is deliberately limited: a single Kubernetes cluster
>   can run in multiple zones, but only within the same region (and cloud
>   provider).

I hope it helps.

Comment: Your link dicusses a managed Kubernetes setup on GCE & AWS. I am setting it up myself, so the limitations or GCE & AWS does not apply.

Comment: I see. So the answer from Владимир Тюхтин is what are you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

EKS (AWS Kubernetes Service) does in the way you described.

An EKS cluster consists of two VPCs:

- An AWS-managed VPC that hosts the Kubernetes control plane. This VPC does not appear in the customer account.
- A customer-managed VPC that hosts the Kubernetes nodes. This is where containers run, as well as other customer-managed AWS infrastructure such as load balancers used by the cluster. This VPC appears in the customer account.

https://aws.github.io/aws-eks-best-practices/reliability/docs/controlplane/

[image]